# Electron window store build crashing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, windows-store, electron-builder

We are using electron builder with reactJs to create windows application our application packaged well in .exe with the help of electron-builder but not able to published on windows store even followed the guide provided by windows-electron-store.

Getting error while executing this command:

```
electron-windows-store --input-directory ./dist --output-directory ./output --package-version 1.0.0.0 --package-name cra-electron
```

You can see I provide all required arguments --input-directory, --output-directory, --package-version and --package-name except --flatten because its no more required according to this commit [dcc654d](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/electron-windows-store/commit/dcc654df2ec2bb706dc4f1664aa4775ab320541e)

**Configuration**

DesktopConverterLocation:C:\ProgramFiles\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppConverter_2.1.4.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe

Expanded Base Image:           C:\Users\aashir\Downloads\Windows_BaseImage_DAC_18362_V1.wim

Publisher:                     CN=developmentca

Dev Certificate:               C:\Users\aashir\AppData\Roaming\electron-windows-store\developmentca\developmentca.pfx

Windows Kit Location:          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64

Starting Conversion...

Cleaning pre-appx output folder...

Copying data...

Creating manifest..

Creating appx package...ad

**Error:**

```
events.js:174
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

 Error: spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64\makeappx.exe ENOENT
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
Emitted 'error' event at:
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:12)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

At this time you've probably guessed that you're missing the 'makeappx.exe'. Try the Windows Kit location with 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\App Certification Kit'. This is the location that i see in my machine. Make sure you install the latest Windows 10 SDK too.